# Name for two cycles that share edges or are connected by a path?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have a finite graph with nodes $I=\{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n\}$, $i_j$ is always connected to $i_{j+1}$ for $j<n$ (hence $i_1$ need not be connected to $i_n$), and there exist two cycles $C_1 = (i_1, i_2, \dots, i_T, i_1)$ and $C_2 = (i_A, i_{A+1}, \dots, i_n, i_A)$. What kind of properties does this graph or set of nodes have?

Case 1: $T \geq A$. This is like the graph pictured on the left. 
$i_1 = A, i_2 = B, i_3 = C, i_4=i_A = D, i_5 = E, i_T=i_6 = F, i_7=G, i_8 = H, i_9=I.$

Case 2: $T < A$. This is like the graph pictured on the right. 
$i_1 = K, i_2 = J, i_3 = i_T = L, i_4 = M, i_5 = i_A = N, i_6 = P, i_7 = i_n = O$.

[image]

I believe the entire graph is a trail. For the graph on the left we can construct a trail $(F,A,B,C,D,I,H,G,F,E,D)$. On the right, $(L,K,J,L,M,N,P,O,N)$. I know these are Eulerian trails because we use each edge once, but what if these are nodes are only part of a larger graph? Then we say this is an Eulerian subgraph. However, I don't want to rule out the fact that other edges might exist among the nodes in $I$. I am just saying that at least these edges exist.

My hypothesis is that $(i_T, \dots, i_1, \dots, i_T, \dots, i_n, i_A)$ is always a trail, where $i_A$ shows up in the middle either to the left or to the right of $i_T$ in that sequence above. Are there any other properties to discuss here, or is the existence of a trail all that can be guaranteed?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that the graphs as you describe them, without additional edges, have an Eulerian trail, as there are 0 or 2 vertices of odd degree (see the Properties at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).  But if you are allowed additional edges, it suffices to add odd degree vertices and there's no trail.

For instance, add the $H, E$ edge in your graph on the left.  Or the $M, O$ edge on the right.